# Unity3D Android delepoing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, settings, device

Unity intructions abouts Android developement is hard to understand and unclear.
Especially I have problem with [Android SDK setup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html). There has been written that "If the Android device is automatically recognized by the system you still might need to update the drivers with the ones that came with the Android SDK." How I can even know if android device is recognized? How should I check it?
The second problem is there: "Go to Settings -> Developer options, then enable USB debugging." Where that settings are? In unity editor I can't find such a thing. Maybe in SDK or something but I don't know how to get there.
So what should I do? And if you have any advice connected with android please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unity intructions abouts Android developement is hard to understand and unclear.

I agree.

> How I can even know if android device is recognized? How should I check it?

Write to the terminal `adb devices`. If the output list is empty, you should install the latest drivers.

(Your computer may not recognize `adb`. It's an executable in `android/sdk/platform-tools`. Add this path to your system path, because these executables are essentials to deploy to your device.)

> USB debugging

It's on your phone. You may need to enable developer mode first, which varying on different devices.

Comment: I tried adding the path like here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm, but I write adb or adb devices I get "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". But maybe I added path wrong. I used adb as a variable and path is pointing to adb but maybe it should just point the folder. I didn't do anything like that yet. :(

Comment: It should be only the folder. Are you using a full, and correct path? (I assume you using Windows.) Locate the adb.exe in the file browser. Right click on the path field on the top, choose copy path. Now something like `C:/.../android/sdk/platform-tools` should be on your clipboard. Use this. I believe computer restart will be required.

Comment: Ok, path didn't work so I just cd to the folder and than used adb.exe devices and I get this: http://bit.ly/androidSDKproblem. It means I don't have any devices attached or I have an unnamed devise? I have phone plugged in the computer. Shouldn't I have an emulator or something? I don't understand anything :'(

Comment: Ok, I think I did everything properly right now. Thx for help :)